# Retrieving WiFi network in Swift 3

Tags: macos, swift3, wifi

I'm trying to find out what SSID the machine is connected to. Everything I've found is for iOS and is useless. Using the code below, I get an error stating: "'CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo' is unavailable" since it's iOS specific. What's the macOS equivalent?

**Swift 3:**

```
    import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

    var wifiNetwork = "Unknown"
    if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
        for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces){
            let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i)
            let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
            let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString)

            if let unsafeInterfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any> {
                wifiNetwork = (unsafeInterfaceData["SSID"] as? String)!
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the code below to get the current SSID, after checking for internet connectivity.

```
import CoreWLAN

let wifiNetwork = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface()!.ssid()!
```

Answer (score 0):

use answer from Quinn, the God of networking at Apple:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50302

copied here:

```
func currentSSIDs() -> [String] {  
    guard let interfaceNames = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as? [String] else {  
        return []  
    }  
    return interfaceNames.flatMap { name in  
        guard let info = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(name as CFString) as? [String:AnyObject] else {  
            return nil  
        }  
        guard let ssid = info[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String else {  
            return nil  
        }  
        return ssid  
    }  
}
```

Comment: CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo is only available in iOS and tvOS according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo). I can't find an analogue for macOS anywhere.